# Is ${\cal N}=4$ Supersymmetric Yang-Mills in $D=4$ confining?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, confinement

Is ${\cal N}=4$ Supersymmetric Yang-Mills in $D=4$ confining?
Any intuitive reason why or why not?

Comment: what do you mean by confining? IIRC the vev of the Maldacena-Wilson loop is computable at large $N$ and the resulting quark-antiquark potential turns out to be Coulomb-like even at strong coupling.

Comment: Color confining. Confining: all asymptotic states must be color neutral. Even though the Lagrangian contains colored objects, the asymptotic states are all color singlets.

Comment: It is a CFT, I dont know what "asymptotic states" means...

Comment: Do you understand the vanishing of its β function? Do you understand what confinement has to do with infrared slavery?